# Adding script, via plugins, in the admin head

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins

I've made a Wordpress plugin, and I'm trying to add javascript to the admin head. I've tried but couldn't managed to do it, could anyone help? Bellow is what I was going with:

```
  function __construct() {        
    add_action('wp_head', 'wpb_hook_javascript');
  }

function wpb_hook_javascript() {
?>
    <script>
      // javscript code 
    </script>
<?php
```

}

Comment: Great! What is the question?

Comment: @amarinediary dosent work like this, into the plugin file , it works only in function.php ,i wanna do a plugin for putting script into header

Comment: If one of the answers bellow as helped you, don't forget to vote up and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: this would only apply on the frontend. See @amarinediary's answer for the correct Admin implementation.**

Your code to add the hook is currently inside of a `__construct()` function, which would only be triggered automatically if the plugin is a PHP Class. Try taking the `add_action` hook out of that and putting it at the same level as the other function.

```
add_action('wp_head', 'wpb_hook_javascript');

function wpb_hook_javascript() {
?>
    <script>
      // javscript code 
    </script>
<?php
```

Comment: wenn is in the same level as the other function:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

Comment: Sorry, @amarinediary, I was writing mine at the same time you were, edited to point to your answer since you were slightly faster. (I missed that they were looking for the admin side anyway.)

Answer (score -1):

this works!

```
add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'function_name' ));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a function (preferably in the root of your plugin directory) via '[admin_head](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_head/)', like so:

```
function my_custom_admin_script() {

    // get the current files folder name.
    $my_plugin_name = trim( dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ), '/' );

    // get the plugin directory and add folder name.
    $my_plugin_directory = plugins_url() . '/' . $my_plugin_name;

    // enqueue script.
    // See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script-name-reference', $my_plugin_directory . '/js/my-script.js', array( 'jquery' ), filemtime( $my_plugin_directory . '/js/my-script.js' ), true );

};
add_action( 'admin_head', 'my_custom_admin_script' );
```

Change `/js/script.js` to where you script is in your plugin structure.

This will then load the script on WordPress Admin screens - but not the Block Editor. If you want to attach a script in the block editor you should replace `admin_head` with `enqueue_block_editor_assets` - [see the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/enqueue_block_editor_assets/).

Answer (score -2):

You need OOP structured solution which is following.

```
class testing {

public function __construct() {
   add_action( 'admin_head', array($this, 'admin_script'), 10 );
}

public function admin_script() {
  if ( is_admin() ) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">

    </script>';
  };
}

}  

// class object/instance 
  new testing();
```